# Android: Unable to share files to Google Drive, but I am able to compose an email

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am trying to share multiple files of text files named like this, **hello.log**. I am able to successfully share with GMail. However, when I attempt to share via google drive, I get a google drive error saying: **Upload was unsuccessful. Unable to schedule 1 file for upload.** Does this have to do with permission issue such as google drive not having permission to read my storage?

```
private fun sendLogs(context: Context, files: ArrayList<Uri>) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).apply {
            putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files)
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Logs")
            type = "text/*"
        }
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

My URI looks like this

**file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.takshing.android.app.debug/files/Logs/1604519601556.log**

Comment: Permission for what?

Comment: Please give an example of how your uries look like.

Comment: @blackapps No problem, I just updated my question with what my URI looks like after debugging the value. Not sure if this is what you meant. When I mentioned permission I read somewhere that some apps wont be able to be shared to because they dont implement some sort of permission to read files?

Comment: You have file uries. That will not work. Use a FileProvider to serve your files. Then you will have content scheme uries.

Comment: You are still much to vague about permissions. Come to the point please. What have you done? But ... for the directory you mentioned you do not need any permission as it is your apps specific directory.

Comment: @blackapps I read here https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file

Comment: @blackapps It mentioned this following sentence i copy pasted "receiving apps have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which will fail on important share targets, like Gmail, that don't have that permission." when using Uri.fromFile().

Comment: Thank you so much though for pointing this out. I assumed nothing was wrong because the files were being loading to the email app as attachments which led me to falsely believe it should work for google drive. It seems the inner logic is different. I'll try to switch over to FileProvider and re-test with both email and google drive!

Comment: @blackapps you should post a proper answer and Belphegor you should accept it.